# Jmeter : How to overwrite existing result file (csv) and html report when generate report by cmd

Tags: command-line, jmeter

```
C:\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\bin>Jmeter -n -t "C:\jm\ReservationManual.jmx" -l "C:\jm\Result\result1.csv" -e -o  "C:\jm\Report"
```

I used above command line code to generate JMeter report, each time I have to manually delete the contents on Result and Report folder. Other wise I am getting below error

**An error occurred: Cannot write to 'C:\jm\Report' as folder is not empty
errorlevel=1**

Is there any way to overwrite existing result and report file

Answer (score 0):

[image]

this is my solution and worked me I think you will be change parameters (version - path etc.) to yours and get the result.